# Visual Studio Deploying program with access database files

Tags: database, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, publish

For a college project i have a program that contains 3 microsoft access databases and several text files which hold data, when running the program through visual studio everything works fine. However to try and run on another computer for real world testing the program can not access the databases because of no MS Access, i saw that to solve this i have to publish the program. Now when i publish the program the databases and the text files are not published with the application, therefore when i startup the program it informs me that the database can't be found. What do i do?